# CSS - No scrollbars in head code

Tags: html, css, head

I am trying to show scrollbars at all times for my website but only have access to the head (using Adobe Muse).

I was trying to use this code but it didn't work for me:

```
<html>
<style>
html {
    overflow-y: scroll; 
}
</style>
</html>
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Could you post some sufficient code to check it? It's best if get demo.

Comment: What browser and OS are you using? OSX/iOS does not display scorllbars at any time.

Comment: On what platform or device are you testing? For instance, if you're on OS X (where the OS hides the scroll bar), simply applying `overflow-y: scroll` will not work because the browser will always hide the scroll bars (until an action is performed). You can disable this behavior, but my guess is most users won't.

Comment: Yeah. need to know what browser is hiding them...

Comment: It is Safari on OS X. Anyway to show them without getting the user to disable the feature?

Comment: Safari on OS X only display them if you have a non-touch input device (like a mouse with a scrollwheel). Otherwise **there will be no scrollbars**

Answer (score 1):

[This should work](http://jsfiddle.net/BramVanroy/n90zh6ot/). Did you put the style tag in the right place? Your whole HTML structure should look like this:

```html
<html>

<head>
  <style type="text/css">
    html {
      overflow-y: scroll;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <!-- Some content -->
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try doing it like this

```
html {
    overflow-y: scroll;
    height: 100%;
}
```

You may need to add !important to `overflow-y: scroll !important;` if it is being over-ridden by the rest of the CSS.

Answer (score 0):

**1.)**

```
html {
  overflow: -moz-scrollbars-vertical; 
  overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

**2.)**

```
html { height:101%; }
```